# Can I put "as evidenced by" as a non-essential clause here?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, modifiers

> Overall, as corruption is widespread, as evidenced by corruption at
> both the elite and grassroots levels, socialism does not work.

Is the above sentence correct? I tried to modify "widespread" by the clause "as evidenced by...".  I wanted to say that that corruption is widespread as evidenced by corruption at both the elite and grassroots levels. Therefore, socialism does not work as corruption is widespread. Did I manage to do it correctly?

Comment: The grammar is good.

Comment: Yes, but "as" is a preposition, so it's a preposition phrase not a clause.